# mix-blend-mode: How do I prevent a part of the circle from blending with the other circle

Tags: html, css

How do I make only a part of a circle not blend with the color of the other circle. Please refer to the below picture. I want the top left portion of the green circle to blend with the white circle but not the top right portion of it.

[image: 1st Task]

**codepen**: https://codepen.io/gauravthantry/pen/wmjGwp?editors=1100

Below is my code

```css
.circle{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.whiteCircle{
  background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  
  
}
.greenCircle{
  background-color: rgb(10,210,30);
  
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.blueCircle{
  background-color: rgb(0,20,210);
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>1st Main Task</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="container">
      <section class="row">
          <section class="col-xs-1">
             <section class="whiteCircle circle"> </section>
        </section>
          <section class="col-xs-1">
             <section class="whiteCircle circle"> </section>
        </section>
        <section class="col-xs-1">
             <section class="whiteCircle circle"> </section>
        </section>
        <section class="col-xs-1">
             <section class="whiteCircle circle"> </section>
        </section>
        <section class="col-xs-1">
             <section class="whiteCircle circle"> </section>
        </section>
      </section>
      <section class="row">
        <section class="col-xs-1"> 
          <section class="greenCircle circle"> </section>
        </section>
        <section class="col-xs-1">
          <section class="greenCircle circle"> </section>
        </section>
        <section class="col-xs-1">
          <section class="greenCircle circle"> </section>
        </section>
        <section class="col-xs-1">
          <section class="greenCircle circle"> </section>
        </section>
      </section>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.green, .green:before, .green:after, .blue, .blue:before, .blue:after {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.green, .blue {
  position: relative;
  opacity: .5;
}

.green:before, .blue:before {
  top: -50%;
}

.green:after, .blue:after {
  bottom: -50%;
}

.green {
  background-color: rgb(10,210,30);
}

.green:before, .green:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
}

.blue {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(0,20,210);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.blue:before, .blue:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <title>1st Main Task</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="container">
      <div class="circle">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="green"></div>
          <div class="blue"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="circle">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="green"></div>
          <div class="blue"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="circle">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="green"></div>
          <div class="blue"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="circle">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="green"></div>
          <div class="blue"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="circle">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="green"></div>
          <div class="blue"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Vitaly! THank's a lot it worked. Also, could you please add comments to the code? Because I am not able to understand where does the code prevent the right part of the topmost green circle from blending  with white.

Comment: Hey. Sorry, I do not speak English well.
I can say that I added a property `overflow: hidden;` for a class `.wrapper` and it has hide all elements outside this class

Comment: It alright. Will look into it myself. Anyways thank you for you help.